# Galaxy S4 does not dispatch the intents for ISO 14443A-3 tags

Tags: android, nfc, samsung-mobile

We are testing our existing NFC solutions with the S4 at the moment and we found out that when we have tags which implement only the ISO/IEC 14443A-3 protocol Android does not dispatch the intents to the registered apps. We are using the NfcA.transceive() to send some proprietary commands to the tags. On all other Android phones this is working (including Nexus 4). On the S4 I can hear a beep when the tag is tapped, but my app gets no intent. Has something changed in the tag dispatch system?